# .height() .width() doesn't adjust to change in size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image that adjusts to screen size but the `.height` and `.width()` doesn't adjust, leaving my `margin-left` and `margin-top` from changing. Is there a way to make it adjust?

```
    var $src = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#overlay').append('<img class="image" src="' + $src + '" />'); 
    var $image = $('img');
    $('.image').css('max-height','80%');
    $('.image').css('max-width','90%');
    $('.image').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.image').css('top', '50%');
    $('.image').css('left', '50%');
    var $height = $image.height();
    var $width = $image.width();
    $('.image').css('margin-top', (($height/2)*-1));
    $('.image').css('margin-left', (($width/2)*-1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8a4Y/

Comment: They will always be 0, because you have two images ($image does not have a source). Besides, that information will only be available after the image has been loaded.

Comment: As you have positioned fixed try applying margin: 0 auto instead of top left 50% technique.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the image isn't loaded when you messure it. So height, width will always be zero.

http://jsfiddle.net/W8sNw/

So what you can do is to add a handler for the `load event` and when that is fired you could execute your code:

```
var $src = $(this).attr("href");
$('#overlay').append('<img class="image" src="' + $src + '" />'); 
var $image = $('img');
$image.on("load",function(){ // This is the new stuff, it listen to the load event 
                             // which is fired when the image is loaded and the size
                             // size is known

   var $height = $image.height();
   var $width = $image.width();
   $('.image').css('margin-top', (($height/2)*-1));
   $('.image').css('margin-left', (($width/2)*-1)); 
   console.log("Height: " + $height);
   console.log("Width: " + $width);
})
```

I also included an example which a more optimized code. For example every time you use a selector the JavaScript will search in the DOM for that element. You should only to this once, have a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/W8sNw/2/

Comment: You should combine all the css props into one function.

Comment: @Jashwant I updated the second example. I want the first one to refelect OPs syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $src = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#overlay').append('<img class="image" src="' + $src + '" />'); 
    var $image = $('img')
$image.ready(function(){

    $('.image').css('max-height','80%');
    $('.image').css('max-width','90%');
    $('.image').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.image').css('top', '50%');
    $('.image').css('left', '50%');
    var $height = $image.height();
    var $width = $image.width();
    $('.image').css('margin-top', (($height/2)*-1));
    $('.image').css('margin-left', (($width/2)*-1)); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The [jquery resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) might help.

Put your code into a function and call the function in the resize event.